# Adding item in combobox when combobox is created on click event

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to add items in comboBox. I know how to do this, with `myBox.AddItem "words"` However I have an issue to implement this to my code as I create the comboBox on click event :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim editBox As MSForms.Control
    Dim testBox As ComboBox
    Static i
    Set editBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    i = i + 1
    With editBox
        .Name = "cmBox" & i
        .Top = i * editBox.Height + 10
        .Left = 130
    End With
End Sub
```

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you

Comment: At what point are you trying to populate the combobox?

Comment: You could use: .List = Array("test1", "test2")

Comment: @EvR It works perfectly. Thank you for the tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the items are known at the time you're creating the controls, ...you can do that in the handler directly. Just set `testBox` to your `editBox` reference:

```
Set testBox = editBox 'basically cast from MSForms.Control to MSForms.ComboBox
testBox.Add "test1"
testBox.Add "test2"
```

On the other hand, if the items are *not* known at the time you're creating the controls, you have a problem:

```
Dim testBox As ComboBox
```

The object is locally-scoped, and goes out of scope as soon as the click handler exits.

You need to hold on to it. Move that declaration to module-level (and qualify it, for consistency):

```
Private testBox As MSForms.ComboBox
```

Then you can invoke `testBox.Add`.... the problem is that you're going to be adding more than one control, so you can't just have one field like this. Have a `Collection` instead:

```
Private dynamicControls As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set dynamicControls = New Collection
End Sub
```

Now when you create a dynamic control, add it to the collection with a key:

```
Set editBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
'...
dynamicControls.Add editBox, editBox.Name
```

---

If you need to handle events for these dynamic controls, you'll need a different setup though, with an instance of a custom class for each dynamic control:

```
'Class1
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents box As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub box_Change()
    '...
End Sub

Public Property Get Control() As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set Control = box
End Property

Public Property Set Control(ByVal value As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set box = value
End Property
```

Then when you create a dynamic control, you add it to a new instance of that class instead:

```
Set editBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
'...
Dim dynamicHandler As Class1
Set dynamicHandler = New Class1 'todo rename that class
Set dynamicHandler.Control = editBox
dynamicControls.Add dynamicHandler, editBox.Name
```

Now when you're ready to add items to a given box, retrieve the control from the `dynamicControls` collection:

```
With dynamicControls("cmBox1")
    .Add "test1"
    .Add "test2"
End With
```

Comment: For the first method, I don't understand at each steps where am I. I mean am I supposed to be in UserForme file or somewhere else ?

Comment: Also when you say add to the collection with a key, I am not sure how to do so

Comment: @LyessD sorry, that `Class_Initialize` should have been `UserForm_Initialize`. Fixed. Yes, it's in the form's code-behind, if that's where you're creating/adding the controls. Declare the collection at module level. The collection key is the 2nd argument given to the `.Add` method.